# How long does it take for Multibit to synchronize an old wallet?

Tags: synchronization, multibit, bip37-bloom-filter

I'm trying to restore my old wallet which I had created on Multibit around 2016 and held a fraction of a bitcoin, as far as I can remember.

I have not touched the wallet for years until today when I found the Mnemonic words by chance. So I have downloaded the ancient [Multibit](https://download.cnet.com/MultiBit/3000-2078_4-75915646.html) client and restored the wallet. Now it is trying hard to synchronize the wallet. I have a decent laptop but the fan does not turn off while it is syncing. So I suppose there are lots of calculations involved. Though I have no clue what is that.  In any case, it is so damn slow: after several hours only 20% is synchronized. Why?

I'm wondering why does it take so long? How long should I expect for it to be fully synchronized? and how much disk space will it need?
I'm worried that it fills out laptop's 256GB SSD and still does not sync.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember MultiBit uses BIP37 bloomfilters to request data from full nodes. BIP37 was deprecated years ago and newer full nodes no longer provide this network service. According to [Luke-jr's data](https://luke.dashjr.org/programs/bitcoin/files/charts/services.html), there are only 662 listening nodes that still provide the "bloom" network service. [image]

It may be slow, because your MultiBit client is having trouble finding a decent full node to serve it data. You might be able to sidestep this issue by importing the wallet into a different wallet, or by starting up your own full node of a sufficiently old version and connect your MultiBit to that directly.

Answer (score -2):

Its downloading blocks of the blockchain and depending of speed it could takes 1-2 days

Comment: If I remember correctly, multibit was an SPV wallet using BIP37 bloom filters. If that's right, it's not downloading blocks.